# Gmail account in Mail on SnowLeopard: how well does it work?

Tags: snow-leopard, mail.app, gmail, imap

I am using a gmail account in Mail (via IMAP) on Lion, and it works well. My dad just set up a gmail account and he is on SnowLeopard. Does a gmail account work correctly in Mail (also via IMAP) on SnowLeopard? If not, what are the issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you are configuring Gmail for IMAP and not POP. Google has posted extensive instructions on optimizing Gmail with Apple Mail. You should check them out.

[Apple Mail 4 with Gmail](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=180188)

[Gmail Recommended Client Settings for IMAP](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=78892)

There is also this excellent article from *MacWorld*, March 14, 2011: [How to make Gmail work well with  [Apple] Mail](http://www.macworld.com/article/157846/2011/03/mailgmail.html).

Comment: Yes, IMAP is the intention. Thanks for specifying (I'll update the question), and thanks for the instructions!

Answer (score 2):

It works just as well as in Lion.